# How can i make a search Api using MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to make a search api and i am using the mongoose `FIND` this work find but not in all cases where like in lower case and uppercase, can someone please help me with a valid code that work fine.  thanks in advance..

This is my controller code:

```
search: function(req, res, next){
    Player.find({firstName :req.params.firstName}, function(err, user){
      if(user.length === 0 ){
        res.json({message: "No Player found"});
      }else{
        res.json(user);
        next();
      }
    });
  },
```

Comment: Just to clarify, are you asking for a way to do case-insensitive find?

Comment: No am asking for a better way to do the search

Comment: So you mean when you want to do a first name search in lower case it shouldn't return results for first names in upper case too?

Comment: No i want it to return names for uppercase too